# How to call php function with <li> onclick event using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Could you help me how to call PHP function (which is calling an external server) by using AJAX if I am using  `onclick` event?

```
<div class="container">
<h3 style=color:blue;>INFORMATION </h3>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color:lightblue" >
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"   style=color:blue;> Information <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a onclick="get_inf1()" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;">Submenu_1</a></li> 
    <li><a onclick="get_inf2()" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;">Submenu_2</a></li> 
    <li><a onclick="get_inf3()" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;">Submenu_3</a></li> 
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the called php function's begin codes are:

```
<?php 
function get_info1()
{
    $bdy = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    $bdy.= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
    xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    $bdy.= "<soap:Body>";
    $bdy.= "<GetInformation xmlns=\"http:// website  /\" />";
    $bdy.= "</soap:Body>";
    $bdy.= "</soap:Envelope>\r\n";
    $req = "POST /data.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

etc ...

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I tried this solution with example.php and script.php (answer from Nick Kuznia) - and it works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

example.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3 style=color:blue;>INFORMATION </h3>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color:lightblue" >
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"   style=color:blue;> Information <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="uniqueId01">Submenu_1</li> 
        <li id="uniqueId02">Submenu_2</li> 
        <li id="uniqueId03">Submenu_3</li> 
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
    $.get('/path/to/script.php', { menu: this.id }, function(data){
        $('body').append(data); //do something with whatever data is returned
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

path/to/script.php:

```
<?php

switch($_GET['menu']){

    case 'uniqueId01':
        menu1();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId02':
        menu2();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId03':
        menu3();
        break;
    default:
        someDefaultFunction();
        break;
}

function menu1(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 1! '; //do something
}
function menu2(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 2! ';
}
function menu3(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 3! ';
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution with example.php and script.php (answer from Nick Kuznia)  - and it works correctly!  Thank you!